# How to create a thumb and push it to s3 using django-imagekit?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-imagekit

I am using Django 1.6.2 and django-imagekit==3.2.1.

I have the following in my model:

```
class Avatar(models.Model):
avatar = ProcessedImageField(upload_to=/here/the/path,
                             format='JPEG',
                             options={'quality': 60})
avatar_thumb = ImageSpecField(source='avatar',
                               processors=[ResizeToFill(150, 150)],
                               format='JPEG',
                               options={'quality': 60})
```

On upload my avatar is correctly saved to my S3, but nothing happens with my avatar_thumb.

How can I modify the avatar_thumb (rename it, setting s3 path) and save it also to the S3?

Answer (score -1):

Checkout [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), you can then set your 'upload_to' to a path in an S3 bucket.